# How to get lighttpd server address after redirect?

Tags: http, http-proxy, lighttpd

This is me lighttpd.conf:

> $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/ws" {
> proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => "8088" ) ) )
> proxy.header = ( "upgrade" => "enable" )
> accesslog.filename = "/log/proxy.log"                                    }

I want to get the forwarding relationship (port and IP) for each connection. What should I do? Thank you

Comment: There does not appear to be any printing in the log

Comment: Do you want to trigger a custom log line from within the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the forwarding relationship (port and IP) for each connection. What should I do?

Start with the official documentation (RTFM): [mod_accesslog](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAccessLog)

Also make sure that the user under which you are running lighttpd has access to write to `/log/proxy.log`

log entries are written when the connection is closed, so if you are testing with a long-lived websocket connection, you are not going to see the log entry until after the connection is closed.